# how to parse JSON string with value as array

Tags: android, json, parsing

i need to parse the JSON data given below.

```
{"result":[{"bookId":142645,"bookpb":"MF",
"bookTs":1328999630000,"clipStatus":"D","bookDetail":{"arrival":1,"purchase":1,"sold":1},
"hierarchies":{"categories":["4"],"events":[]},"shopId":769752},
```

upto "sold" it is working fine.but when i am trying to parse categories it is not working.
given below is the code for parsing the data.

```
ArrayList<BookItem> resultdata = new ArrayList<BookItem>();
 JSONArray jsonArray = (new JSONObject(inputString))
    .getJSONArray("result");

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
item = new BookItem();
item.setbookId(jsonObject.optString(book_ID));
item.setPurchase(jsonObject.optInt(PURCHASE));
item.setArrival(jsonObject.optInt(ARRIVAL));
item.setSold(jsonObject.optInt(SOLD));
item.setbookTs(jsonObject.optString(book_TS));
JSONObject hierarchies=jsonObject.getJSONObject(HIERARCHY);
item.setCategory(hierarchies.getInt("categories"));
resultdata.add(item);
  }
```

can anybody help me???

i came to know that this is the problem of

```
 {"categories":["4"],"events":[]}
```

data.how can i parse this array value?

Comment: it is always advisable to check your json string with http://jsonlint.com/ if it is complex. It seems the mentioned one is in incorrect format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

categories is an JSONArray in order to get JSONArray

replace

```
item.setCategory(hierarchies.getInt("categories"));
```

with

```
item.setCategory(hierarchies.getJSONArray("categories").getInt(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

For your purpose the best solution is probably GSON library. It do serialization and deserialization on its own and you will get your objects.
http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/